# Center a div with dynamic width in a parent where the width can be bigger than the parent

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position, margin

Okay I hope I can make clear what I need.

I have 5 Divs: a wrapper, div 1, div 2, div 3 and div 4.

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="one">1</div>
    <div id="two">2
        <div id="four">4</div>
    </div>
    <div id="three">3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main{
    height:200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float:left;
}

#one{
    min-width:100px;
    max-width:200px;
    background-color:#cccccc;
    height:100%;
    float:left;

}

#two{
    width:50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#ccffff;
    float:left;
 }

#three{
    min-width:100px;
    max-width:200px;
    background-color:orange;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}
#four{
    min-width:52px;
    max-width:200px;
    background-color:pink;

}
```

[Please see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nv96frkr/)

Div 4 is contained in its parent div 2. Div 4 always needs to be centered from div 2 even if it gets bigger then div 2.

How to do this. At this moment the div4 is always in div2. Played around with floats, positioning and margins, but since the div 4 width is dynamical, I can never make it center.

Lets say I have entered text in div 4, then I want to let it look like this:

```
 _______________
 | 1  |2  | 3   |
 |  __|___|___  |
 |  |div4 txt|  |
 |  |________|  |
 |____|___|_____|
```

I hope this masterpiece makes it clear. Div4 can be bigger or smaller depending on de text in it.

If it is easier to put div2 and div4 in a new wrapper, it's fine by me, but div 1 and div 2 should always be "connected" to div 2 (also tried this, but this resulted in div 1 and div 3 to be apart from div2)

I have also tried:

1. searching this site :)
2. searching google
3. margin: 0 -50%;
4. position: relative;
5. display: inline-block;
6. display: tabel; (and cells)
7. etc

Hope someone can help.

ps also div 1 and 3 aren't always displayed. ! can be hidden, 3 can be hidden but both can be hidden too

Comment: centered vertically or horizontally?

Comment: horizontally, I think I need to add the extra wrapper of div 2 and 4....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use absolute positioning.

```
#four{
    min-width:52px;
    max-width:200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color:pink;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: calc(50% - 100px)
}
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5dh66t14/

Comment: Problem here is that div 4 is too big. If I set it to the smallest with like 60px, the div4 isn't centered anymore. Div 4 's length depends on the text in it, this changes each time the page is loaded. Sometimes its 60 px other times 100px or maxed at 200px hence the max and min width

Comment: @Maurice, ok I've got a modification of that fiddle that uses a little javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/5dh66t14/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this CSS:

```
#four {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c2q945p0/)**

Comment: Excellent idea (wish I'd thought of it), but actually because OP requires that the width of the element is determined by its content (not a fixed px value in the style), it doesn't quite work.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  This may require some JavaScript.